# Kohana ORM-MPTT to hierarchical array

Tags: arrays, kohana, hierarchical, mptt

Respective All! Does anybody know method that retrieves me a MPTT tree as hierarchical array?

Like follows:

> array ("1"=>  array(
>          "10"=> array("100"),
>           "11" => array("110"=>
>                               array("1110") ) ) )

Unfortunately, ORM::Factory('Tree1')->fulltree()->as_array()
can't do that :-(

Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: Can you post the db schema you use for this? Tree traversal shouldn't be too diffcult - what have you tried?

Comment: What I need is JSON-fromatted ORM-MPTT output. And formatted with strong accordance to tree hierarchy